# Refactoring Sections in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, refactoring

I have a few Views that use

```
view.cshtml
...
@{
   //pagination code 
 }
....
@section Name
{
   <link rel="next" href="@baseUrl@pagination.NextPage" />
   <link rel="next" href="@baseUrl@pagination.NextPage" />
}

...
```

to insert META Tags into the layout page.

The section code is identical in every view. Is there a better way to do this without duplicating code in each view?

Comment: "The section code is identical in every view" - do you mean that there isn't any view without section if yes then you can just remove this section and move the appropriate code to layout page

Answer (score 0):

If this section is identical in every view you probably should move it to layout, if not consider:

- Creating partial view within this section, this way you have to change it in one place:

  `@section Name
      {
         @Html.Partial("ViewName")
      }`
- Create separated layout just for pages with this section